# JS Regex to find href of several a tags

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a regex to find the contents of the hrefs from these a tags :

```
<p class="bc_shirt_delete">
   <a href="/CustomContentProcess.aspx?CCID=13524&amp;OID=3936923&amp;A=Delete" onclick="javascript:return confirm('Are You sure you want to delete this item?')">delete</a>
</p>
```

Just the urls, not the href/ tags.

I'm parsing a plain text ajax request here, so I need a regex.

Comment: Did you try to write it?

Comment: Please format the code with the correct indentation, it is unreadable

Comment: With javascript? Is that all a text (in text area, for instance) or HTML which is a part of page?

Comment: sorry, posted the wrong paste.  Yeah it's plain text from an ajax request or else I'd use jQuery.

Comment: I see you use HTML5-Data Attribute, so why not access it throught its API ?
http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/

Comment: So, you alreay have jquery on your page?

Comment: tip: ajax requests existed long before jquery and have nothing to do with jquery

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can try this regex:

```
/href="([^\'\"]+)/g
```

Example at: http://regexr.com?333d1

**Update:** or easier via non greedy method:

```
/href="(.*?)"/g
```

Comment: That's works great, but there a link element. Would it be possible to use the p's class name to aid the search?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you want changed? Could you please explain?

Comment: So the search would be just for a hrefs within p tags with the class name `bc_shirt_delete .

Comment: SOme tinkering and I got there. Thanks!

Comment: It is incomplete as it doesn't cover all the situations. Check my answer down the page: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40887021/1867650

Answer (score 9):

This will do it nicely. http://jsfiddle.net/grantk/cvBae/216/

Regex example: https://regex101.com/r/nLXheV/1

```js
var str = '<p href="missme" class="test"><a href="/CustomContentProcess.aspx?CCID=13524&amp;OID=3936923&amp;A=Delete" onclick="">delete</a></p>'
    
var patt = /<a[^>]*href=["']([^"']*)["']/g;
while(match=patt.exec(str)){
  alert(match[1]);
}
```

Comment: Works like charm, exactly what I was looking for. Thankyou

Comment: `<a class="test" href="https://goog.le/">nopes</a>` will fail, for example. Many other cases will fail as well. Sure, it works for the question; but just an advice for those who landed here searching for a regex.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @Gogol.
I've added an updated regex here: https://regex101.com/r/nLXheV/1
Let me know if there are any use cases that it might fail on.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a robust solution:

```
let href_regex = /<a([^>]*?)href\s*=\s*(['"])([^\2]*?)\2\1*>/i,
    link_text = '<a href="/another-article/">another article link</a>',
    href = link_text.replace ( href_regex , '$3' );
```

[image: Coloured href RegEx from http://www.regexr.com]

#### What it does:

- detects a tags
- lazy skips over other HTML attributes and groups (1) so you DRY
- matches `href` attribute
- takes in consideration possible whitespace around `=`
- makes a group (2) of `'` and `"` so you DRY
- matches anything but group (1) and groups (3) it
- matches the group (2) of `'` and `"`
- matches the group (1) (other attributes)
- matches whatever else is there until closing the tag
- set proper flags `i` ignore case

Answer (score 4):

You may don't need Regex to do that.

```
o = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
urls = Array();
for (i =0; i < o.length; i++){
   urls[i] = o[i].href;
}
```

If it is a plain text, you may insert it into a displayed non DOM element, i.e `display: none`, and then deal with it regularly in a way like I described.

Answer (score 3):

It might be easier to use jQuery

```
 var html = '<li><h2 class="saved_shirt_name">new shirt 1</h2><button class="edit_shirt">Edit Shirt</button><button class="delete_shirt" data-eq="0" data-href="/CustomContentProcess.aspx?CCID=13524&amp;OID=3936923&amp;A=Delete">Delete Shirt</button></li><li><h2 class="saved_shirt_name">new shirt 2</h2><button class="edit_shirt">Edit Shirt</button><button class="delete_shirt" data-eq="0" data-href="/CustomContentProcess.aspx?CCID=13524&amp;OID=3936924&amp;A=Delete">Delete Shirt</button></li><li><h2 class="saved_shirt_name">new shirt 3</h2><button class="edit_shirt">Edit Shirt</button><button class="delete_shirt" data-eq="0" data-href="/CustomContentProcess.aspx?CCID=13524&amp;OID=3936925&amp;A=Delete">Delete Shirt</button></li>';
$(html).find('[data-href]');
```

And iterate each node

**UPDATE** (because post updated)

Let html be your raw response

```
var matches = $(html).find('[href]');
var hrefs = [];
$.each(matches, function(i, el){ hrefs.push($(el).attr('href'));});
//hrefs is an array of matches
```

Comment: As I said, it's a plain text ajax request that I'm parsing.

Comment: @InfraStank once that is ajax response and you already have a jQuery, you can simply do something like above. No need to use Regexp there.

Answer (score 1):

I combined a few solutions around and came up with this (Tested in .NET):

```
(?<=href=[\'\"])([^\'\"]+)
```

Explanation:

(?<=) : look behind so it wont include these characters

[\'\"] : match both single and double quote

[^] :  match everything else except the characters after '^' in here

+   : one or more occurrence of last character.

This works well and is not greedy with the quote as it would stop matching the moment it finds a quote

Comment: Look behind is not supported in JS. Check http://www.regexr.com. See my answer, not as tidy and compact though.

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = "";

str += "<p class=\"bc_shirt_delete\">";
str += "<a href=\"/CustomContentProcess.aspx?CCID=13524&amp;OID=3936923&amp;A=Delete\" onclick=\"javascript:return confirm('Are You sure you want to delete this item?')\">delete</a>";
str += "</p>";
```

---

```
var matches = [];

str.replace(/href=("|')(.*?)("|')/g, function(a, b, match) {
  matches.push(match);
});

console.log(matches);
```

or if you don't care about the href:

```
var matches = str.match(/href=("|')(.*?)("|')/);

console.log(matches);
```

Answer (score 0):

how about spaces around = ?
this code will fix it:

```
var matches = str.match(/href( *)=( *)("|'*)(.*?)("|'*)( |>)/);
console.log(matches);
```

Comment: Good, but still needs some work. Check my answer on this page: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40887021/1867650

Answer (score 0):

It's important to be non-greedy. And to cater for —matching— `'` *or* `"`

```
test = "<a href="#" class="foo bar"> banana 
        <a href='http://google.de/foo?yes=1&no=2' data-href='foobar'/>"

test.replace(/href=(?:\'.*?\'|\".*?\")/gi,'');
```

**disclaimer**: The one thing it does not catch is html5 attribs data-href...

Answer (score 0):

In this specified case probably this is fastest pregmatch:

```
/f="([^"]*)/
```

- gets ALL signs/characters (letters, numbers, newline signs etc.) form *f="* to nearest next ", excluding it, flags for example */is* are unnecesary, return null if empty

but if the source contains lots of other links, it will be necessary to determine that this is exactly the one you are looking for and here we can do it this way, just include in your pregmatch more of the source code, for example (of course its depend from source site code...)

```
/bc_shirt_delete">\s*<a href="([^"]*)
```