# Writing regex to match an href attribute

Tags: regex

For example `href://http://facebook.com/groups/`

or even

`href://http://northumbria.ac.uk/brochure/courses/fees/?view=Standard`

this is what i got so far

```
href="http://.(\..+)+(/.+)*
```

What I was thinking maybe if it is secured, allow https, and possible www. after the http:// so that would be

```
href="https?://(w{3}|.+)(\..+)+(/.+)*
```

So my question is there a way to do this better, more efficiently or simply just make it look nicer ? Or am I missing something there ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JS Regex to find href of several a tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13802334/js-regex-to-find-href-of-several-a-tags)

Answer (score 0):

I just googled it..third hit:

[google link](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/8-regular-expressions-you-should-know/)

```
/^(https?:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([\/\w \.-]*)*\/?$/
```