# Get only URL "href" from string

Tags: javascript

Suppose I have a **String** in my DB like this:

```
<a class=' text-info' href='description/Q0RFU0NJRDM=/Acetaminophen (Tylenol) Poisoning'&#47;>Acetaminophen (Tylenol) Poisoning<a &#47;>

<a class=' text-info' href='description/Q0RFU0NJRDQ=/Achalasia'&#47;>Achalasia<a &#47;>
```

How can I get only URL part in these strings through **Javascript**?

The output should be:

```
description/Q0RFU0NJRDQ=/Achalasia 

description/Q0RFU0NJRDM=/Acetaminophen (Tylenol) Poisoning
```

Comment: do you have them as strings or `a` elements on a webpage

Comment: why do some one keep html tag in database?

Comment: Why would you have your HTML tags inside your database ?

Comment: You have these tags in the html document right?

Comment: i have posted answer,which will work as you expect,

Comment: @Clonkex Why not? I don't feel like explaining my post so wouldn't qualify as a good answer hence it being posted as a comment. This is also the first time I have seen anyone complain for putting a quick simple solution posted in the comments especially since this question is a duplicate... Would you rather me mark it as a duplicate since your answer is also a match of an existing one?  Update: *"Comment removed & question flagged as duplicate"* fine by me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JS Regex to find href of several a tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13802334/js-regex-to-find-href-of-several-a-tags)

Comment: @NewToJS I deleted my comments if you wish to do the same :)

Comment: @Clonkex No it's fine. I will keep them in place.  **:)**

Comment: @Mohamed-Ted its string that is why i have written it in bold

Comment: can u answer the question. :) @JinsPeter

Comment: @doe CyberAbhay's answer seem to work. He has taken the HTML as string

Answer (score 1):

You can get the urls as follows:
Firstly, you store the anchors in an array

```
urls  = ["<a class=' text-info' href='description/Q0RFU0NJRDM=/Acetaminophen (Tylenol) Poisoning'&#47;>Acetaminophen (Tylenol) Poisoning<a &#47;>",
"<a class=' text-info' href='description/Q0RFU0NJRDQ=/Achalasia'&#47;>Achalasia<a &#47;>"];
```

Now, using map method of array

```
var _urls = urls.map(function(url){
   var div = document.createElement('div');
   div.innerHTML =  url;
   return div.children[0].getAttribute('href');
});
```

You can iterate over the array and create a temporary div and add the anchor as innerHTML to get an HTML Element and return the href property of the element.

**SNIPPET**

```js
urls  = ["<a class=' text-info' href='description/Q0RFU0NJRDM=/Acetaminophen (Tylenol) Poisoning'&#47;>Acetaminophen (Tylenol) Poisoning<a &#47;>",
"<a class=' text-info' href='description/Q0RFU0NJRDQ=/Achalasia'&#47;>Achalasia<a &#47;>"];

var _urls = urls.map(function(url){
   var div = document.createElement('div');
   div.innerHTML =  url;
   return div.children[0].getAttribute('href');
});

console.log(_urls);
```

Comment: That could risk something being injected if the strings are not sanitized when saved.

Comment: I suppose the strings are sanitized before storing in DB.

Comment: @Mohamed-Ted Further  the node is not appended in DOM its just created on memory just to get the href property.

Comment: That's true, I was just mentioning that it can be potentially risky

Answer (score 0):

If those were in an HTML page:

```
var aList = document.querySelectorAll("a");
var aArray = Array.prototype.slice(aList, 0);
aArray.forEach(function(aElement){
    console.log(aElement.getAttribute('href'));
});
```

Oh you don't have those in an HTML page. So you can basically do string manipulation:

```
databaseResults.forEach(function(databaseResult){
    var hrefValue = databaseResult.split(" ").filter(function(item){ return item.startsWith("href"); }).split("=")
    return hrefValue.substring(1, hrefValue.length - 1);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use a simple regex like so:

```
var theString = "<a class=' text-info' href='description/Q0RFU0NJRDM=/Acetaminophen (Tylenol) Poisoning'&#47;>Acetaminophen (Tylenol) Poisoning<a &#47;>";
var exp = /href='(.+)'/g;
var match = exp.exec(theString);
console.log(match[0]); //outputs: description/Q0RFU0NJRDM=/Acetaminophen (Tylenol) Poisoning
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:
Here `coll` is non-live collection for DOM elements and is an array like structure over which you can iterate.

```js
var coll = document.querySelectorAll('.text-info');
    console.log(coll.length);
    for(var i=0;i<coll.length;i++) {
        console.log(coll[i].getAttribute('href'));
    }
```

```html
<a class=' text-info' href='description/Q0RFU0NJRDM=/Acetaminophen (Tylenol) Poisoning'&#47;>Acetaminophen (Tylenol) Poisoning<a &#47;>

<a class=' text-info' href='description/Q0RFU0NJRDQ=/Achalasia'&#47;>Achalasia<a &#47;>
```

Comment: He said they were strings in a DB; your answer assumes they are in the DOM.

Comment: @Clonkex If that is the case, how is your solution going to help? Shouldn't then a query be written instead of `console.log` in your solution? I have asked him the question though! Question is not very clear.

Comment: My solution assumes he knows how to get the data out of the DB but not how to extract the substring from the string. My use of `console.log()` is to demonstrate how to use resulting variable, and is quite common.

Comment: @Clonkex Yeah, assumption! It is entirely possible that he has these tags in DB, reads them on server side and sends back as html to the browser. Possible?

Comment: Well he didn't specify. You're _assuming_ he has them in the DOM with your answer. It's normal to assume. It's also all we can do since he didn't tell us one way or the other. Personally I think it's obvious that he means he simply wants to get the `href` part out of a normal string, but if I'm wrong he will correct me.

Comment: @Clonkex Yeah same with me. Please have patience when you also made an assumption and don't be quick to judge other's solution.

Comment: I feel it's fair that I assumed to be correct, when that's what he actually _said_. For your answer to be correct he would have had to leave out fairly important information and mean something other than what he said. But my intention was not to judge, only to point out that I thought you may have mis-read the question, so apologies if I came across as judgmental.

Comment: @Clonkex No worries! I also didn't mean that you apologize to me. I just wanted both of us to wait for clarification since we both agree that the problem is poorly structured. By the way it's unusual to the best of my knowledge that one keeps these tags in DB. So my assumption(which I thought was fair) was to think it is in DOM. :)

Answer (score 0):

From the question it's not really clear whether the input is string of `a` or dom elements:

in case they are strings we can use a simple RegEx: `/href=(["|'])(.*)\1/`,
that will capture anything between `'` or `"` after a `href=`.

```js
var strings = [
`<a class=' text-info' href='description/Q0RFU0NJRDM=/Acetaminophen (Tylenol) Poisoning'&#47;>Acetaminophen (Tylenol) Poisoning<a &#47;>`,
`<a class=' text-info' href='description/Q0RFU0NJRDQ=/Achalasia'&#47;>Achalasia<a &#47;>`
]

var urls = strings.map(s=>{
  return /href=(["|'])(.*)\1/.exec(s)[2];
})

console.log(urls)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is you answer which will give you only url from your anchor-tag HTMl

```js
var data = '<a class="text-info" href="description/Q0RFU0NJRDM=/Acetaminophen (Tylenol) Poisoning"&#47;>Acetaminophen (Tylenol) Poisoning<a &#47;>';

var subString = 'href="';
var endString = '>';
var index =1;
function substringcheck(data,subString,endString,index){
var urlstart =  data.split(subString, index).join(subString).length;
var urlend = data.split(endString, index).join(endString).length;

var res = data.substring(urlstart+6,urlend-6);
return res;
}

var result = substringcheck(data, subString,endString, index);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: I think this is not what he wanted. In your example the string is already the part he wanted. The OP wanted to know how to extract that part (i.e. `description/Q0RFU0NJRDM=/Acetaminophen (Tylenol) Poisoning`) from the original string (i.e. `<a class=' text-info' href='description/Q0RFU0NJRDM=/Acetaminophen (Tylenol) Poisoning'&#47;>Acetaminophen (Tylenol) Poisoning<a &#47;>`).

Comment: @Clonkex i have updated my code to take anchor tag HTML as input and give desired output

Comment: Nice, looking better now. I think the OP is spoiled for choice :P